# How to count distinct flags in the sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

BELOW IS SNIPPET OF MY DATA
Here is the sample creation code of testing.

```
CREATE TABLE MYGROUP ( Category,PERSON,Flag ) AS
          SELECT 'Cat1','A','1' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat1','A','0' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat1','A','1' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat1','B','1' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat1','B','0' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat2','A','0' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat2','A','0' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat2','A','0' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat2','B','1' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat2','B','1' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat2','B','0' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat3','X','0' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Cat3','Y','0' FROM DUAL;
```

Desired Output:

Category - Count of Distinct Persons with Flag = 1

```
Cat1 - 2
Cat2 - 1
Cat3 - 0
```

I need to get my code in Big query to get distinct counts of persons. It shouldnt double count.

Comment: `DUAL` is an Oracle concept (and perhaps others) but certainly NOT correct for SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation

```sql
SELECT
    Category,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Flag = 1 THEN PERSON END)
FROM MYGROUP
GROUP BY Category;
```

A more efficient version uses two levels of aggregation, this allows an index `Category, Flag, Person` to be used.

```sql
SELECT
    Category,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Flag = 1 THEN CountPerson END)
FROM (
    SELECT
        Category,
        Flag,
        COUNT(DISTINCT Person) AS CountPerson
    FROM MYGROUP
    GROUP BY Category, Flag
)
GROUP BY Category;
```